# "Unable to load suggested edit - please try again"

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, suggested-edits

I'm encountering an error: "Unable to load suggested edit - please try again" while trying to load a suggested edit review from the question page on Ask Ubuntu.

[image: Err]

As [confirmed by David in the chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8478287), the issue seems to be network-wide.

Comment: Just noticed the same at german.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks for reporting. We're digging into what's caused these issues. :)

Comment: This bug seems to have been fixed. @Catija can you please confirm?